# sapui5/openui5 namespace mixup jQuery.sap

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am confused after one hour of try and error, I figured out [how to load the jQuery.sap.storage namespace](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.storage.html). The trouble was caused by "jQuery" vs "jquery". The documentation says "jQuery.sap.storage". But the filename says "jquery". I required the namespace with "jquery", but call the instance with "jQuery". Is the mixup between filename (matching the require) and the namespace name (matching the instance name) a typo or intention?

[image: sapui5 namespace mixup]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Storage Type undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981156/jquery-storage-type-undefined)

Comment: If someone needs only the plain `jQuery` without the storage usage, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63618539/5846045

Answer (score 3):

This does not look like a typo. jQuery itself is contained in a file starting with the prefix "jquery". I assume that the same pattern is used in UI5/OpenUI5 for jQuery related stuff. The same for the function, jQuery internally uses the $ as alias for the variable jQuery. Obviously the developers decided not to use the alias but the variable. So UI5/OpenUI5 just makes use of the proven patterns.

Comment: I don't think so, because this way dependency injection does not work. The Interpreter can't resolve the namespace.

Comment: Could you clarify your statement? Which dependency injection? Why can't the interpreter resolve the namespace?

Comment: It is not possible to use sap.ui.define to define a control like this: sap.ui.define(['jquery.sap.global', 'jquery/sap/storage', 'sap/ui/base/Object'], function(jQuery, MockServer, Object) {//impl});

Comment: 'jquery.sap.storage'?