# jQuery Storage Type undefined

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I used a [jQuery storage](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/jQuery.sap.storage) to store data.

```
oStore = jQuery.sap.storage(jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local);
oStore.put("id", rep);
```

but I am getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'Type' of undefined

Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UI5 version 1.58+

The module `sap/ui/util/Storage`, which is available since UI5 1.58, replaces `jQuery.sap.storage`.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/util/Storage",
  // ...
], function(Storage/*,...*/) {
  "use strict";
  const storageType = Storage.Type.local;
  const storage = new Storage(storageType);
  // ...
});
```

API reference: [`sap/ui/util/Storage`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/module:sap/ui/util/Storage)

### UI5 version < 1.58 (Previous answer)

The reason, why `jQuery.sap.storage` is not defined, is that the module has not yet been loaded (and thus not globally accessible). Whenever you're using jQuery APIs, make sure to resolve its dependency first, and then use the resolved parameter name instead of accessing APIs globally as mentioned in the [documentation](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/030fcd14963048218488048f407f8f34):

> Use only local variables inside the AMD factory function, do not access the content of other modules via their global names, not even for such fundamental stuff like `jQuery` or `sap.ui.Device`. You can't be sure that the modules are already loaded and the namespace is available.

Example:

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "jquery.sap.storage",
  // ...
], function(jQuery/*,...*/) {
  "use strict";
  const storageType = jQuery.sap.storage.Type.local;
  const storage = jQuery.sap.storage(storageType);
  // ...
});
```

[image: UI5 API Reference jquery.sap.storage]

API reference: [`jquery.sap.storage`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/jQuery.sap.storage)