# Cannot find name 'jQuery' error in controller.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am developing a UI5 app in VS Code.
I added a new count function to the `*.controller.js` file, and in order to display the count from the server, I am using jQuery like in the following code:

```js
jQuery.each(this._mFilters, function (sFilterKey, oFilter) {
  oModel.read("/portfolios/$count", {
    filters: oFilter,
    success: function (oData) {
      var sPath = "/" + sFilterKey;
      oViewModel.setProperty(sPath, oData);
    }
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:
[image: Screenshot of VSCode error]

Does anyone know why was the error triggered and how it can be fixed?
Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you include jQuery in the page?

Comment: I have it in package.json, where it's usually declared.
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1"
  }
}

Comment: That just means it's available to be imported.  If this is a node thing, you will have to `var jQuery = require()` something to get jQuery in there

Comment: Though, if you are using node, I'm not sure why you are relying on jQuery for looping logic.

Comment: I had to edit my answer below. Using `jquery.sap.global` is no longer recommended according to this doc: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/a075ed88ef324261bca41813a6ac4a1c. Instead, require `sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery` **or** remove jQuery dependency altogether since `jQuery.each` is easily replaceable with browser's native JS APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `this._mFilters` is an object. In that case, try with:

```js
Object.keys(this._mFilters).map(sFilterKey => {
  const oFilter = this._mFilters[sFilterKey];
  oModel.read("/portfolios/$count", {
    filters: [ oFilter ],
    success: function(sCount) {
      const sPath = `/${sFilterKey}`;
      oViewModel.setProperty(sPath, +sCount);
    },
  });
});
```

Also the parameter [`filters` awaits an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884700/5846045) instead of a single Filter instance.

---

If jQuery is still preferred, include **`"sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery"`** (formerly `"jquery.sap.global"`) to the dependency list of the controller.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  // ...,
  "sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery",
], function(Controller,/*...,*/ jQuery) {
  // jQuery is here available
});
```